# What is busy calls?

Tags: iphone, applications, sim, phone.app

In phone settings on iOS I have a button called "SIM apps" when clicked it gives me a button to open an app called Busy Calls, the app starts with the screen on the left.

If I click "Edit SMS templates" it opens the screen on the right.

[image]
[image]

Sometimes the app appears on my phone while it is locked, and I have to reboot the phone.

Anybody knows what this app does?

iPhone 7, iOS 10.3
No jailbreak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIM apps are small apps provided by your carrier on your SIM card. This is not an iOS or iPhone feature and you should contact your carrier regarding this.

On first glance, the app you show appears to be able to send messages when you are currently busy on a call. iOS provides this feature separately in Settings → Respond with Text.